# Questions regarding PHP's password_hash()

Tags: php, password-hash

I have a few question regarding PHP's `password_hash` function.

I've noticed that if do

```
echo password_hash("12345", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

then I get somethng like

```
$2y$10$PgMmle9Ue4o3m7ITJcGa0ucmWXSZgqbJBF9I4qd/aqzn/vQIwbi/O
```

So my questions are

1) Wouldn't the part of `$2y$10$` give a hint of what algorythm was used and make it easier for an attacker to know what the original string was?

2) Can I just store the string after `$2y$10$` and concatenate it anytime I have to work with the password?

3) Why `$2y$10$` is used? Could that change in the future? So in my DB I have passwords with `$2y$10$` and some with `$2y$25$`? and everything would run smoothly using `password_verify`?

Comment: Yes, a hint is given, but that does not really lower security. The level of security is _not_ defined by obfuscation, but by the quality of the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, that's what it's for. Wouldn't objectively ease cracking hashes. It's the most common hashing and stretching algorithm anyway, easy to infer from the hash length even without the prefix. Storing it separately isn't even security by obscurity, but just pointless code. (3) Yes, it's for forward-compatibility to new algorithms in the future.

Comment: Imagine you have a database of users with hashed passwords. In the future you start using a different algorithm, you can't force all of your users to update their passwords so that they are hashed with the new algorithm, can you? Prefixes in hashes like these identify the algorithm so that upon login you can verify both passwords using your old hashes and ones using your new algorithm. I doubt you have ever received an e-mail from any company forcing you to update your password or lose your account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From reading the manual of [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) it looks like in `$aa$bb$`, `bb` seems to stand for the "cost" of the algorithm used and `aa` seems to be (at least currently) always `2y`.

> Wouldn't the part of `$2y$10$` give a hint of what algorythm was used and make it easier for an attacker to know what the original string was?

Yes it would give a hint, but

1. so does the entire rest of a string for many functions (for example, an md5/sha1 hash will always consist of exactly 32/40 hexadecimal characters).
2. this shouldn't be an issue, because you shouldn't rely on obfuscation anyway, but on a strong algorithm (as arkascha correctly points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425658/questions-regarding-phps-password-hash#comment52716660_32425658)).

> Why `$2y$10$` is used?

Because someone thought it was a good idea.

> Could that change in the future?

I think so.
The second part is varying already, and the first part is mentioned in [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) as `the "$2y$" identifier`, but there is no guarantee that no other identifier will be added.

> So in my DB I have passwords with `$2y$10$` and some with `$2y$25$`? and everything would run smoothly using password_verify?

Take a look at the [examples in the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-examples) - that's already how it is.
`password_hash(..., PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` seems to produce a prefix of `$2y$10$`, but `password_hash(..., PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12])` produces `$2y$12$`.

> Can I just store the string after `$2y$10$` and concatenate it anytime I have to work with the password?

I would advise against this.
You could probably make it work, and you could probably even prevent it from breaking on arbitrary changes, but if your only concern is that the encrypted string hints the encryption method used, a better option would be to add an additional layer of symmetric encryption.
For example:

```
$password = password_hash("12345", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$key = pack('H*', md5('lorem').md5('ipsum')); // Must be 16, 24 or 32 bits
$secret = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $password, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
// Store $secret in the database
```

This way, if an attacker does not have your source code, they have no way of telling what the encrypted data means, and if they do have access to your source code, they can just take a look at what encryption's being used anyway.

But again, even if the attacker knows that `password_hash` and `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` are being used, they shouldn't be able to crack it.

Comment: great answer, thanks! and thank you for the detailed information, exactly what I needed